# AD programs per roaming profile

Tags: active-directory, user-profile, roaming-profile

Is it possible to make programs roaming with each user profile?
I wish to make it so that each user with a roaming profile has their own programs that load with their profile?

Also, is it possible to ignore all programs on the computer itself when the profile is loaded?

Thanks, Matt.

Comment: You might want to look into Remote App or VDI. Then the computer just becomes a dumb terminal with minimal programs. The rest of the programs can be published per user via Remote App or virtual desktop. It will require a more work and infrastructure than what you are probably seeking. But, apart from software distribution policies and application restriction policies I can't think of any other way. And I don't think those will get you all the way there.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 99% of programs are installed at Computer level, no you cannot.
You could bypass the issue installing the same programs on all computers the user will need to logon. Profile will carry the (user level) settings.

Another option is to virtualize the applications. Basically it consists in setup and configuration capture and "packaging" of all the new files and registry entries in a single and portable package. After that you can copy this package in the roaming profile and link the main exe where it suits the user best.

VMware ThinApp is the best solution to do so otherwise you'd can also evaluate Cameyo (free & open source) and several others: http://alternativeto.net/software/vmware-thinapp/